# finding the readabilty score of a text in a dataframe

Tags: r

hi I hope everyone is doing well. I am trying to work with a data frame consist of two variables one is the essay number and 2nd is the text of that essay like

```
Df

 Essay    context
  1        Eiffel tower is located in France ~~~
  2        prince of Persia and related text
```

what I want is to calculate the readability score of the text for a single essay which will be used for assessing the time for an article to be featured article by using the readability test.

using the KoRpus package in R  when I apply this code i got the error

```
ARI(df, parameters = c(asl = 0.5, awl = 4.71, const = 21.43))
```

> error: Missing data: sentences!

any help would be highly appreciated.

Note: I will be finding the readability score on individual essays not as a whole document 
thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Maybe you need to give that function a vector of essays?... `ARI(df$context, parameters = c(asl = 0.5, awl = 4.71, const = 21.43))`

Comment: I have done that as well but that give me the following                                  Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘readability’ for signature ‘"factor"’

Comment: Maybe your context field is a factor. In that case... try `ARI(as.character(df$context), parameters = c(asl = 0.5, awl = 4.71, const = 21.43))`

Comment: don't know how to set a language in ARI function